# ggplotly blocks ggplot2 theme

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm finding the plotly package blocks/obscures certain arguments supplied to ggplot's `theme()`.

Looking at base ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp))+
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(gear)))+
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(0, 0, 20, 0)),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )+
  ggtitle("Title")
```

Puts legend below x axis and increases space between title and top of graph, as expected.

**BUT:**

```
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp))+
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(gear)))+
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(0, 0, 20, 0)),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )+
  ggtitle("Title")

ggplotly(p = p)
```

Completely ignores these `theme()` elements.

Does anyone have any solutions that work with ggplotly?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `ggplotly(p = p) %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = "h"))`, and find more at https://plotly.com/r/legend/

Comment: I've come across that, thanks. Any suggestions for the title margin??